# Does .NET on Silverlight have the equivalent of firstObjectCommonWithArray in Objective-C?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Here is what is the official explanation of firstObjectCommonWithArray in Objective C:

> Returns the first object contained in the receiving array that’s equal
>   to an object in another given array.
>
> Original signature is - (id)firstObjectCommonWithArray:(NSArray
>   *)otherArray

Is there anything like this for a `List` in .NET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no direct single method but you could certainly build one using linq.

```
var first = array1.FirstOrDefault(x => array2.Contains(x));
```

Comment: What should I expect from this if array2 does not contain x? null?

Comment: @EthanAllen `null` or an empty struct depending on the type of the array.

Comment: @Ethan Allen: The default value for reference and nullable types is Nothing.  If you want to define a default you can do DefaultIfEmpty() (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx for reference).